# IntelliJ Grails view always dissapearing

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

When I open my grails project I always get something like this:

[http://imgur.com/SK4ybSm](https://imgur.com/SK4ybSm)

Then to get to "grails view" I have to click it, then double click on my project root and then View --> Tools Windows --> Grails View to get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXTLV.jpg

Anyone knows how to fix this, so I don't have to do this every time ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug since other modes of the project view do persist, I've submitted it to YouTrack, please follow for updates:

- [IDEA-168623](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168623) Grails mode of the Project View doesn't persist